# Writing Smart Contract

Tags: blockchain

I'm new to the whole crypto currency chain.

I have a question that keeps bugging me and can't seem to find an answer to

My question is Do you need to create your own Contract Source/Smart Contract Code to be able to execute another one that is already on the blockChain?

For example
0x3301ee63fb29f863f2333bd4466acb46cd8323e6

If I wanted to transfer the tokens from the above contract what would I need to do to complete the transfer?

Also with Below ScreenShot
What fields need to be filled out?

Thank you

[image: write Contract]

Comment: Welcome! I'd like to see if I'm understanding right - you own tokens on this contract, and you'd like to transfer them, and you're asking how, is that correct?

Comment: hi and thank you for your response. yes that is correct. I'm just trying to understand, if i was to transfer the funds from the contract that i have brought token into, how i would be able to transfer them.

Comment: this is a bit out of the scope for the site, but I'd recommend using a wallet (like MetaMask) - most allow importing a token by address, and expose an interface that makes transferring easier